# How can i read a result from postresql query with node js server?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm working with a node js server, I had to set up the cookies part. I put in my db salt and password and for the login I extract only salt at first and with bcrypt I hash password+salt.

I need to read salt value from results.

```
    const client = await pool.connect();
    const result = await client.query("SELECT salt FROM utenti WHERE mail = '"+username+"'");
    console.log(result.rows);
    //Here miss the part where I take value from result.
    /*
    const salt = I take from result
    const pass = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    const result_1 = await client.query("SELECT mail FROM utenti WHERE mail = '"+username+"' AND password = '"+pass+'");
    */

    cookies.set(sessionId,{ mail: username});
    res.cookie('auth', sessionId);
    res.status(200).send('You are logged in').end() 
    client.release();
```

result.rows have this output:

```
[ salt: '$2a$10$/hmb4.0S218SA4OyxWJLf.' ]
```

I know that is Json format but JSON.parse() don't work on it and i can't read salt value.

Thank you for help and time.

Comment: result[0] would be enough

Comment: console.log(result.rows[0].salt); It work thank you Anatoly